How do I implement token based authentication on a spring webflux api?
I've tried working with both ReactiveAuthenticationManager and a WebFilter. In both cases, the execution flow is some form of this:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String token = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (!jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid token");
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        String username = jwtTokenProvider.getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return userRepository.findByEmail(username)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("User not found")))
            .map(user -> {
                System.out.println("hydrated user from token. File is JRAM");
                System.out.println(user); // this prints user
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user.getUsername(),
                        null,
                        Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))
                );

                return authenticationToken;
            });
    }
}

As commented above, token is decoded and user is hydrated correctly. I believe the problem stems from binding it to the ReactiveSecurityContextHolder. I tried different variations of the below:
SecurityContextImpl securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl(authentication);
                        Context context = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withSecurityContext(Mono.just(securityContext));

In one instance, I tried setting security context and returning that to the mono. In another instance, I tried just setting the authentication directly on ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication. No dice. When I was working with ReactiveAuthenticationManager, I also tried ServerSecurityContextRepository
@Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange swe) {
        String authHeader = swe.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map(SecurityContextImpl::new);
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }

Didn't help. Trying to read authentication from the ReactiveSecurityContextHolder in a subsequent mono method fails with a NullPointerException. So I'm guessing the setting breaks but I can't debug that cuz switchIfEmpty and onErrorResume just print out whatever they're given all the same.
Most stack overflow answers on the subject are outdated, using deprecated methods. Also none of these work for me while retrieving the user. Authentication is probably failing but at some point, I could access user parameter although it was blank. Other times, request just backs off with 401
Below is the securityConfig
http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                    // bunch of stuff
                    return config;
                }))
                /*.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)*/
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> {
                    authorizeExchangeSpec.pathMatchers(
                            "api/v1/user/login",
                            "api/v1/user/register","webjars/**",
                            "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html",
                            "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll();
                    authorizeExchangeSpec.anyExchange().authenticated();
                })
                .addFilterAt(jwtAuthenticationFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .build();

Kindly help spell out the necessary steps to pass my user to the security context and retrieve it from controller methods. I'm on spring boot 3.3.4. Thanks

handing out JWT tokens to browsers is not recommended, spring does not recommend it, oauth2 strictly recommends not to implement, so i dont really understand why you are trying to build a non recommended security solution.

spring guidelines for SPA applications https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297 and oauth2 recommendations for password token flow (handing out a token after providing username and password) https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/

@Toerktumlare wow! I'm just seeing your comment. I wasn't aware. We will look into your recommendation

With a simplistic version of your JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager and the below code, I'm able to access Authentication inside a controller.
I hope I understood the issue correct.
SecurityConfig
import no.mycompany.webflux.JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .anyExchange().hasRole("USER")
                )
                .addFilterAt(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .build();
    }

    private AuthenticationWebFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        var authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager);

        authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(exchange -> {
            String authHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization");
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                var token = authHeader.substring(7);
                // instance is passed to JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager#authenticate
                return Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token, token));
            }
            return Mono.empty();
        });

        return authenticationWebFilter;
    }
}

Controller
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SomeController {

    @GetMapping
    public Mono<String> sayHello(Authentication authentication) {
        return Mono.just("Hello World " + authentication.getName());
    }
}

Update Added implementation of my mock JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Collections;

@Component
public class JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        // to get token: authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        // for this demo, we return a fixed user
        return Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                "user1",
                null,
                Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")))
        );
    }
}

build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.4.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.7"
}

group = "no.mycompany"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}



It would have helped if you posted your full setup so I don't tinker further with divergent trials. I don't know what the contents of your authenticationManager are. Your jwtAuthenticationFilter is basically same with my authenticationManager. Is the functionality meant to be duplicated? I tried using Authentication on the controller as is, same old story

@IWantAnswers: Added implementation for my mock JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager

@IWantAnswers: Regarding "Your jwtAuthenticationFilter is basically same with my authenticationManager.": The new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token, token) is passed to the JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager where user details are fetched. The filter just extracts token from bearer.

not working for me https://pastebin.com/TBhX0ad7. I'm either dumb or cursed. Or both

Just to be sure, I pasted your static user in jwtAuthManager. Same behavior with mine ie request doesn't fail with 401 but there is no response and it doesn't hit the controller either. Just a 200 with content length 0

@IWantAnswers: I'm testing with Postman, how are you testing this? Let me create a GitHub repo for this.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I'm revisiting this for the purpose of completion and posterity. @Roar's answer hints at the solution but excludes actuals a live project is likelier to entail. Building upon his submission, what currently works involves the following classes:
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                    // bunch of config
                    return config;
                }))
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> {
                    authorizeExchangeSpec.pathMatchers(
                            "api/v1/user/login",
                            "api/v1/user/register","webjars/**",
                            "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html",
                            "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll();
                    authorizeExchangeSpec.anyExchange().authenticated(); // NOTE THIS
                })
                .addFilterAt(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .build();
    }

    private AuthenticationWebFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        var authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager);

        authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(exchange -> {
            String authHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization");
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                var token = authHeader.substring(7);
                // System.out.println(token); // correctly logs
                // instance is passed to JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager#authenticate
                return Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token, token));
            }
            return Mono.empty();
        });

        return authenticationWebFilter;
    }
}

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String token = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (!jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid token");
            return Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication failed")); // terminate request with 401 and fail message? Returning just Mono.error proceeds to controller, which is unwanted
        }
        String username = jwtTokenProvider.getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return userRepository.findByEmail(username)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("User not found")))
            .map(user -> {
                //System.out.println(user); // correctly logs

                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, token,
                        Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
            });
    }
}

And for retrieval on the controller side,
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Flux<SomeDocument>> fetchDocuments(Authentication auth, @PathVariable String id) {
    User user = (User) auth.getPrincipal();

    // work with user.getId()
    }

I believe you can jwtTokenProvider off some internet tutorial but the above successfully binds decoded user to reactive security context.
